# how to get OAuth 2.0 access token using google service accounts on Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

I am developing an android app where I need to consume Google Cloud Platform REST API. This API is not supported for google android library and I have to call using REST. API needs oauth 2.0 access token for authorization. How can I achieve this on android side?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following link will help you in achieving the desired:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: This is related to google sign in on android. I am not looking for this. simple access token to authorize REST API.

Comment: @ShahnazKhan: You need to use Google Sign In for Android as Google have stopped taking web login requests from Android. You can use GoogleSignInAccount.getIdToken() to get the access token you require.

Comment: @Himesh, I am not talking about general user sign in. Clearly mentioned 'service accounts' in question title. I hope you read it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and using library `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev136-1.23.0'` I can get oauth2.0 access token for google service account.

Comment: Isn't this for server to server? How you manage to get in android application?